# How to get all XML values into list with out know names?

Tags: java, xml

know anyone of you how can I get all elements from XML and put it into an List?

XML:

```
    <ins_1 id="0">
        <mov>000</mov>
        <add>001</add>
        <sub>010</sub>
        <cmp>011</cmp>
        <and>100</and>
        <or>101</or>
        <xor>110</xor>
    </ins_1>
    <ins_2 id="101">
        <clr>0000000</clr>
        <neg>0001000</neg>
        <inc>0010000</inc>
        <dec>0011000</dec>
        <asl>0100000</asl>
        <asr>0101000</asr>
        <lsr>0110000</lsr>
        <rol>0111000</rol>
        <ror>1000000</ror>
        <rlc>1001000</rlc>
        <rrc>1010000</rrc>
        <jmp>1011000</jmp>
        <call>1100000</call>
        <push>1101000</push>
        <pop>1110000</pop>
    </ins_2>
```

There it's my XML with all values, I want to make a function which I can put all my values into a HasMap. More exactly I want something like that 
function(ins_1) and that will give me the attributes and values to can put into an Map.
And after I will run the function in my HapMap I will have
myMap.

```
key: mov      values: 000
key: add      values: 001
key: sub      values: 010
```

And so on...

I've search on internet every where to find any solution... But in all solution, on every one... I need to use my attribute name to get values, something like that .getAttribute("mov") and I don't want something like that...

So if anyone know how to can I solve that... pleas show me any solution

Thx :D

Comment: [`Node.getChildNodes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes--), [`Node.getAttributes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes--) or [`document.getElementsByTagName("*")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName-java.lang.String-), etc…

Answer (score 0):

Make use of XML parsers such as DOM or SAX or any other. For instance, in DOM parser you can use

> element.getAttribute(// your case)

and

> element.getElementByTagName(//your case)

Now after you get these value just insert them into Hashmap. You can find many tutorials online.